# How to solve SIGSEGV in my code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Could someone help me with my problem?

I wrote program and it gives me segmentation fault and I don't know what I can do with it, I was trying few hours to solve it but I couldn't d.

If someone could help it would be great!

Here' s my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

inline int fastScanfInt(FILE *input, int *x);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    int t = 0;
    fastScanfInt(stdin, &t);

    int tmp = 0, test = 0;
    test = fastScanfInt(stdin, &tmp);

    while(test != EOF)
    {
        v.push_back(tmp);
        test = fastScanfInt(stdin, &tmp);
    }

    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    int pos = 0, c, v_size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        if(v[pos] % 2 == 0)
        {
            c = v[pos + 1];
            it = v.begin();
            std::advance(it, pos + 1);
            v.erase(it);
            v_size = v.size();
            pos += c % v_size;
            if(pos > (v_size - 1))
                pos -= v_size;
        }
        else
        {
            c = v[pos];
            it = v.begin();
            std::advance(it, pos + 1);
            v.insert(it, (c - 1));
            v_size = v.size();
            pos += c % v_size;
            if(pos > (v_size - 1))
                pos -= v_size;
        }
    }



    for(int i = pos; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
}

inline int fastScanfInt(FILE *input, int *x)
{
    register char c = getc(input);

    if(c != EOF)
    {
        (*x) = 0;
        for( ; ((c < 48) || (c > 57)); c = getc(input));

        for( ; ((c > 47) && (c < 58)); c = getc(input))
            (*x) = ((*x) << 1) + ((*x) << 3) + c - 48;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using gdb to investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should always ensure the `pos` i in bounds when indexing `v`. Giving it an odd number of inputs will cause the `if(v[pos] % 2 == 0)` line to fail because pos will go too far.

Similarly, the `std::advance(it, pos + 1);` can bring you out of bounds. Giving it an even number of inputs can do that.

Giving it three numbers works without segfaulting because the second number is stored, but the third isn't. The `while(test != EOF)` I believe fails to store the final number in the vector.

I haven't actually fixed the code myself, but by looking at where it crashes, I'm pretty sure if yo can fix these mistakes, you'll be in a better position.